# Why Ubuntu 16.04 installer not recognizing unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an un-allocated space which I can see in Windows disk manager as following (78GB)

[image].

I also checked GPart software in live Ubuntu which is showing following picture.   cant see 78GB un allocated space. Its showing 113GB space. Dont know why.

[image]

Same is the installer. I can not click on + icon to create a partition on un allocated space.

[image]

Can some one please advise on it? Is it due to number of partitions in Windows. Should I need to delete more partitions in Windows so that Ubuntu installer may recognize it?

Comment: A drive can have only four primary partitions and it has already four. You could delete one of these and create an extended partition in the free space which can contain more standard partitions.

Comment: @Jean-Marie I deleted Multimedia G: drive. Unallocated space increased in Windows disk manager. But it still didnt recognized by Ubuntu installer. It is still 122GB unusable space. Any further hint?

Comment: Try to create an extended partition in the unallocated space.

Comment: When I click on unallocated space. I can't + sign enabled so that I can create a partition over it. :(

Comment: Using gparted from the live CD, make sure you have no more than 3 primary partitions. In the available space, create an extended partition. In the extended partition create an ext4 partition leaving space for a swap partition. create a swap partition also.  Then try the installer